# A particle moves on a horizontal line so that its coordinate at time $t$ is $x=\ln(1+2t)-t^2+2, t\geq 0.$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

A particle moves on a horizontal line so that its coordinate at time $t$ is $$x=\ln(1+2t)-t^2+2, t\geq 0.$$

i.) Find the velocity and acceleration functions.

ii.) When is the particle moving forward or backward?

iii.) When is the particle speeding up or down?

---

Just need some verification for any of which you know of.

i.) The velocity function is $x'(t)=\displaystyle\frac{2}{1+2t}-2t$. The acceleration function is $x''(t)=\displaystyle\frac{-4}{(1+2t)^2}-2.$

ii.) For $x'(t)>0$, particle moves forward. For $x'(t)<0$, particle moves backward. Using sign analysis, $x'(t)<0$ for $t \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $x'(t)>0$ for $t \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

iii.) Particle speeds up when $x'(t)$ and $x''(t)$ have the same signs, else it is slowing. $x'(t)$ and $x''(t)$ have same signs for $t\in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your part $(ii)$ is wrong. For instance, assuming $t \geq 0$, $x'(t) < 0$ on the interval $(\frac{1}{2},+\infty)$, not $(0, \frac{1}{2})$. Have a look at this part again, then you can fix part $(iii)$.